# How to fix odd color banding caused by CSS animation?

Tags: html, css, electron

### Hello everyone.

I have started making a small app in **Electron**, and want to make a loading screen.

But every time I add the animation to the container div, it gives **its background color weird color banding**.

[Here's an image of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Rqx.png)

Basically the top is a color I do not even use anywhere, while the bottom is the actual color I want.

[Here's an image with the animation disabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFuSk.png)

#### What I tried:

1. Ran the website in **Edge**, **did produce the color banding**.
2. Ran the website in the **snippet, did not produce the color banding**.
3. Tried setting the background color in the animation itself, did not fix the problem.

#### Here's my code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600&family=Roboto&display=swap');
:root {
  --main1: #282b30;
  --main2: #1e2124;
  --main3: #16181a;
  --titleFont: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  --textFont: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  --textColor: #ffffff;
}

* {
  font-family: var(--textFont);
  color: white;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.transitionContainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--main2);
  color: var(--textColor);
  font-size: 500%;
  animation-name: hideTransition;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.35, 1);
  animation-delay: 1.25s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes hideTransition {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@keyframes showTransition {
  from {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}

.logoText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -49.258px;
  margin-top: -96px;
}

.loadingBarBack {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: var(--main3);
}

.loadingBarFront {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: limegreen;
  animation: loading 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes loading {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

  <script src="./index.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="transitionContainer">
    <h1 class="logoText">R</h1>
    <div class="loadingBarBack">
      <div class="loadingBarFront"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Thanks for any help in advance!**

Comment: If you view the site on a different display, or system, does the banding persist?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Tried the page on my phone, banding was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Figured it out!

Apparently `animation-fill-mode: both;` caused some of the div to go transparent before the animation even played.

Setting it to `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` fixed it.